# Error while trying to library rJava from python using rpy2

Tags: r, python-3.x, rpy2, rjava

I am getting problem when trying to load `rJava` from Python using `rpy2` package. I have searched and read many questions but yet none fixes my problem .

I have `rJava` properly working installation in my R environment.

```
(base) pri@pri:~$ R

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

> library(data.table)
data.table 1.12.8 using 4 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com
> library(rJava)
>
```

However when I try to load it from Python using `rpy2` then I get error:

```
(base) pri@pri:~$ python3
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 15:48:22) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rpy2.robjects as robjects
>>> robjects.r('''library(data.table); library(rJava)''')
R[write to console]: data.table 1.12.8 using 4 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com

R[write to console]: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/home/pri/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pri/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 416, in __call__
    res = self.eval(p)
  File "/home/pri/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 198, in __call__
    .__call__(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/pri/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 125, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
  File "/home/pri/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/conversion.py", line 44, in _
    cdata = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pri/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py", line 623, in __call__
    raise embedded.RRuntimeError(_rinterface._geterrmessage())
rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded.RRuntimeError: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/home/pri/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have already checked that binaries are in correct place

```
(base) pri@pri:~$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server/
classes.jsa  libjsig.so  libjvm.so  Xusage.txt
```

and configured correctly as per linux settings:

```
(base) pri@pri:~$ cat /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths | grep R_JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH
: ${R_JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/server}
if test -n "${R_JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"; then
  R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${R_JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

I also tried to append this to `.libPaths()` of R out of curiosity but yet no success:

```
JDBC_exe = "/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server/"
robjects.r('''.libPaths(c('{}', .libPaths()))'''\
            .format(JDBC_exe))
```

Any pointer on what I am missing here and how I can fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Most issues related to dynamic linking should resolve when ensuring that the value of the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is compatible with the output from this command:

```
python -m rpy2.situation LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```